# Drop down is lost after saving

Tags: excel, vba

I am populating a worksheet with data from an SQL database using VBA in Excel 2010.

I added Drop downs to some columns for easy editing. The Drop downs are populated with data from a sql table.

I am generating the Drop downs like this:

```
Sub AddLookupToRange(f As tField, r As Range)
    If Not f.IsLookup Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim elems As String
    Dim k As Long

    elems = ""

    For k = 0 To f.Lookup.Elements.count - 1
        elems = elems & f.Lookup.Elements.Items(k) & ","
    Next k
    elems = Left(elems, Len(elems) - 1)

    With r.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlEqual _
         , Formula1:=elems
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

EDIT:

```
Public Type tLookup
    LookupTable As String
    SaveValue As Boolean
    IndexField As String
    ElementsField As String
    LutFilter As String
    Elements As Scripting.Dictionary
End Type

Public Type tField
    Name As String
    ReadOnly As Boolean
    IsLookup As Boolean
    Lookup  As tLookup
    IsMandatory As Boolean
End Type
```

Now the problem: Everything works fine until I save and close the xlsm-file. 
When I reopen it it says, there are unreadable parts in the file and whether I want to repair it. On repair a window opens with the message: "unreadable part was removed. Removed feature: data validation in /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml-Part" (translated from German).

It looks like Excel cannot handle that kind of usage of drop downs. How can I work around it?

EDIT: The error does not occur if I populate the drop down entries with a literal string ("1,2,3"). If I do so, I can save and load the file without error. All Drop downs are restored. Further research shows the problem occurs if the string 'elems' is longer than 254 characters. Conclusion: Drop down can handle longer strings in operation but is limited at save/restore to 254 characters.

Comment: what is tField ? You have a custom class?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I have used the same validation code but just put  elems = "A,B"
    
 :   With Range("A1").Validation   and it works fine including closing and opening. Excel 2016 64 bit.

Comment: It works in Excel 2013 as well. I presume that you are calling this UFD from `workbook_Open`? If so, at what stage do you make the connection to your database?

Comment: @QHarr: yes, I have an array of tField containing all Lookup properties. Within the tField there is tLookup. For saving the elements I use the Dictionary class provided by Microsoft-Scripting. In the end it should not matter to the drop down as I generate a comma separated string out of the elements. The "With" is directly copied from macro recording and elems is replacing the literal string I had as demo.

Comment: How are you calling this ? As per @Zac's comment

Comment: @Zac: No, it is an expicit macro called by another sub "InitTable" manually invoked form the user from the macro list. It creates the worksheet, fetches the data from the db, populated my tfields/tLookups and generally formats the worksheet. it also adds worksheet protection. To be clear: this all works fine. However, there is the problem of saving/loading the worksheets. My guess is Excel has problems storing all the drop down definitions in the file. There are hundreds of them in the worksheets and some my have a hundred elements.

Comment: @QHarr: I had an earlier version with much simpler code adding a drop down with just two options "TBL>DB,DB>TBL"  and only in one column. That worked fine, too.

Comment: That would make sense. Resources issue so removing. Can you see if there is a tipping point?

Comment: I checked the resources. the error occurs even with only two drop downs total, one with two and one with less than 20 elements. I generated the full table and removed all lines but one.